# OCPJP 8 What is a Symbolic link using NIO2

Tags: java, symlink, ocpjp

I am trying to get Java 8 certification i already have Java 6 a long time ago and Java 7 is my weak point because i havent work with it i am a little confuse.

What is a symbolic Link??

According to wikipedia.

```
In computing, a symbolic link (also symlink or soft link) is a term for any file that contains a reference to another file or directory in the form of an absolute or relative path and that affects pathname resolution.
```

My questions are.

How Java recognize a symbolic link i mean when this would print true?

```
final Path path = ...
System.out.println(Files.isSymbolicLink(path));
```

Perhaps this is a silly question but i really want to know!!

Comment: In unix, it would be a "file" create with `ln -s ....`.and in Windows with `mklink ...`. The OS knows how to distinguish them and `nio` certainly use the JNI for those request. JNI is the Java Native Interface that allows you to implement a java interface in another language like C by the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my ubuntu, I have create two files in `/tmp/`

```
echo "Hello world" > file.txt
ln -s file.txt link.txt
```

If I check for both file .

```
Files.isSymbolicLink(Paths.get("/tmp/file.txt")) //false
Files.isSymbolicLink(Paths.get("/tmp/link.txt")) //true
```

Same would works on Windows with a file and a link made with `mklink`.